# Show table row based on radio selected

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-table, row, show-hide

Again, again, again...issues with my Javascript/jQuery knowledge. 
This time, I want to make a row appears when a radio value is selected. I'm lost on the part where I need to do the row appearing.

This is the row:

```
            <tr class="others" id="others" style="display:none;">
            <th colspan="2"><?php _e('Others', 'shop'); ?></th>
            <td><?php echo fee; ?>&nbsp;&euro;</td>
            </tr>
```

And this is the jquery:

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input').click(function(){
      var isChecked = $('#payment_method_paypal').prop('checked');
      // make the row appear appear if "payment_method_paypal" is checked
      });
```

I tried with alert and it's work, but with the row, I tried every single solution I found on Stack Overflow and on google, but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass boolean to jquerys [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method

> .toggle( showOrHide )
>
> A Boolean indicating whether to show or hide the elements.

This should work

```
var isChecked = $('#payment_method_paypal').prop('checked');
$('#others').toggle(isChecked); //show/hide based on the bool
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brCr3/1/)

Comment: Cool mate ! Thanks, working as charm. I love the power of javascript, but I hate it because of its library. Sometimes you're loosing hours just to find a simple method.

Comment: @demlasjr any time. its easy once you get started ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#others').hide();
```

and

```
$('#others').show();
```

to hide and show that row.

Comment: Tried that already mate, doesn't work :( Here an example: http://jsfiddle.net/brCr3/

Comment: @Johan No idea about that. However, that was like an example, so you can see the checkbox too, as in the question I didn't added that. When I said that it's not working, I was saying that I tried in my website, not on jfiddle :)

Comment: @demlasjr Ive added a fiddle to my comment

Answer (score 1):

***html***

```
<table>
<tr> <td>-------------------</td></tr>
<tr> <td class="trData">-------SHOW------</td></tr>
<tr> <td>-------------------</td></tr>
</table>

<div id="container">
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="red" value="show" checked/>Show<br />
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue" value="hide" />Hide<br />
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#container").find("input[type=radio]:checked").on("click", function() {
    if($(this).attr('value')=='show')
    {
        $(".trData").show()
    }else{
        $(".trData").hide()
    }
});​
```

***JS2*** more compact, but in this case you need set correct value in your radio buttons

```
$("#container").find("input[type=radio]:checked").on("click", function(event) {
    var op= $(this).attr('value');
    jQuery.globalEval('$(".trData").'+op+'()')
});​
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9u3F3/3/)***

​

Comment: `live` is deprecated, use `on`. But there is no need for that in this case, since the radiobuttons arent dynamically generated.

Comment: @AntonBaksheiev Thank you. It's working just fine, but I chosen Johan solution because I needed to change just a word. :)